# Json.NET C#: JToken.Parent is always null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, json.net, parent

I'm working on a Json.NET serialisation system that relies heavily on custom converters, contract resolver, and attributes. The system aims to handle reference deserialisation, including mutual referencing and resolving that isn't order-sensitive. I'm not using Json.NET's native system for this because we have special requirements.

My current system identifies the request for a reference when an object is being deserialised. This reference takes the form of either a numeric ID, or a human-legible string. If the reference's requested object has already been deserialised, then the object in need of the reference is simply assigned its correct value from a large dictionary. If it is not, a "reference request" is submitted. This request contains an object, and an ID.

When I wrote this system, I didn't realise that changing the object in the reference request would not automatically change its recipient. Thus, it simply doesn't work.

However, solving this should be quite simple. If I get an object's encapsulating field-owner (if, for example, Wine is defined within Dinner, I need to retrieve Dinner when examining Wine during deserialisation), I can simply use reflection to set the field. I'm essentially storing the field address. And from what I gather, this should be perfectly possible by traversing the Json hierarchy via `JToken.Parent`. However, when I try and access this field in an object that should have a parent, it's null. I've searched and searched, but I've found no indication that `Parent` is something I need to set myself; I assumed it was handled internally by Json.NET. Why is this null?

Below is an example. FoodExample contains a field of Food, which itself defines a field of Wine.

```
public class FoodExample
{
    // This meal contains a defined instance of Wine, instead of a reference.
    public Food definedMeal = null;

    public FoodExample()
    {

    }

    public void Initialise()
    {
        Food definedMeal = new Food("Steak", new Wine("Pinot Noir", 15.99f));
    } 
}
```

When deserialising Wine using my custom converter, I query the Wine's `JToken.Parent` field, like so:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    Debug.Log("Deserialising definition: " + objectType);

    // Create a JObject. Use it to get a JReader, 
    JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
    JsonReader jsonReader = jObject.CreateReader();

    Debug.Log("Parent: " + (jObject.Parent == null)); // Prints true
}
```

Json output:

```
{
  "definedMeal": {
    "ID": 1,
    "name": "Steak",
    "pairsWellWith": {
      "ID": 0,
      "price": 15.99,
      "name": "Pinot Noir"
    }
  }
}
```

The parent for both objects in this hierarchy appear as null when being passed through my custom converter.

It's probably worth mentioning that I'm working in Unity3D.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30774885/3002584) answer:

> It is not possible to get access to a parent, because parent objects
>   are always created after their children. That is you need to read the
>   json that the object consists of to the end to be able fully construct
>   the object and by the time you've read the last bracket of an object,
>   you've already read all its children. When a child parsed there is no
>   parent yet to get the reference of.